# AsyncStorage not keep data after close the app

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm doing a proof of concept in React Native. My idea is to keep a small amount of data with AsyncStorage but these do not persist after closing and opening the application. The data persists if I do not close the application.

I'm saving values in a reducer, it's my code:

```
    const initialState = {
    data: [],
    fetching: false
};

const todoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('action', action);
    console.log('state', state);
    let copied = Object.assign({}, state);
    switch (action.type){
        case ADD_TODO:
            copied.data.push({ready: false, text: action.payload});
            break;
        case CHECK_TODO:
            copied.data[action.payload].ready = true;
            break;
        case REMOVE_TODO:
            copied.data.splice(action.payload, 1);
            break;
        case GETTING_DATA:
            copied.fetching = true;
            break;
        case SET_STORE:
            console.log('action.payload', action.payload);
            copied.data = action.payload;
            copied.fetching = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_TODO_KEY, JSON.stringify(copied.data));
    return copied;
};
```

I also have a button that looks up the information (not immediately after saving) and is in the sample in text format, this is the code

```
               <Content>
                <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
                <Button rounded style={{width: '100%', marginTop: 10}}
                        onPress={async ()=> {
                            try {
                                const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_TODO_KEY);
                                if (value !== null) {
                                    // We have data!!
                                    console.log(value);
                                    this.setState({value})
                                }else{
                                    console.log('No hay data :c');
                                    this.setState({value: 'No hay data :c'})
                                }
                            } catch (error) {
                                // Error retrieving data
                                console.log('Error', error);
                                this.setState({value: error})
                            }
                        }}>
                    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '100%'}}>Mostar lo guardado</Text>
                </Button>
                {this.props.todos.fetching && <Text>Cargando Lista de quehaceres...</Text>}
                {
                    this.props.todos.data.length > 0 ?
                        this.renderTodoList()
                        : null
                }
            </Content>
```

At the moment of executing the application, saving data and pressing the button the information is displayed, that is, it is being recovered from AsyncStorage, but once the application is closed it does not return data

Comment: You would need to provide code for writing and reading from Asyncstorage you are using in order to get some help.

Comment: code added. Thanks for answering

Comment: Hey so did you ever get to find out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Android with Dev mode, then it is probably that the AsyncStorage got timed out: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/864

Comment: Is not in dev mode

Answer (score -4):

`AsyncStorage` is asynchronous persistent key-value storage system, it can be used at any ware in app.

to use `AsyncStorage` firstly import:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

To set value in `AsyncStorage` can use like below:

```
export function setAsyncStorage(key, item) {
    try {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(key, item);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

for retrieving value from storage use below function:

```
export async function getAsyncStorage(key) {
    try {
        const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do something very similar to this, I updated the publication with my code. Thanks for answering